# Never getting iCloud change notifications

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, icloud

I am working on Core Data syncing over iCloud between two Mac applications. I have it mostly working (based on http://timroadley.com/2012/04/03/core-data-in-icloud/) - data is being synced, but I'm never getting the content change notification I need to merge the changes into my local context.

In my AppDelegate's managedObjectContext method:

```
NSManagedObjectContext * moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
  initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

[moc performBlockAndWait:
^{

  [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) 
    name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification 
    object:coordinator];

}];
```

My observer function never gets called:

```
- (void) mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification*) notification
{
  NSLog(@"Merging changes from iCloud");
  // everything past here is irrelevent - this log message never appears
```

The data store is most certainly being synced - deleting a record in app A and forcing a table reload in app B results in a Core Data fault failure as expected for unmerged changes. Quitting and restarting app B shows the correctly updated data.

A breakpoint on the addObserver call shows it is being called. A breakpoint in `mergeChangesFrom_iCloud` shows that it is not.

Why is the coordinator apparently never sending the `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` as the documentation (and tutorials) claim it should? Where can I begin debugging this?

**Update**

The mystery deepens. Using the Core Foundation function shown here - [NSNotificationCenter trapping and tracing all NSNotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725234/nsnotificationcenter-trapping-and-tracing-all-nsnotifications) - I do not see `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` appear at all among the mass of notifications flying by.

It looks like it's not being posted at all - nor do I see any other Core Data related notifications after the initial load happens on startup.

Comment: Did you find a sollution? I think I have a similar issue that devices not update without a forced quit and restart. I think this happens when the App is in background when a notification comes (in my case) but doesn't check for updates when opened again when loaded.

Comment: No, I never found a solution to this - I believe iCloud syncing just doesn't work properly between two Mac applications on the same machine. Hopefully it will be fixed in the future.

Comment: do you see that your ubiquitous store is updated at all? does it differ between the two apps? (the URL I mean).

Comment: No, the ubiquitous store doesn't get updated. The URLs are different - they are not dirctly sharing a Core Data store. Although it's worth mentioning that I gave up on this approach not long after this question, so something may have changed in a recent update.