# BluetoothManager Framework Notifications List

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

I want to get all the notifications of the BluetoothManager private framework. I've been searching but i only have found two (BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification and BluetoothDeviceDiscoveredNotification).
I'm interesting in a notification that reports if iphone connected/disconnected to a device. If anyone could get me a list of all notifications i will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth device at hand that would result into such events being signaled? if so, why not checking it out yourself -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725234/nsnotificationcenter-trapping-and-tracing-all-nsnotifications (note that last UPDATE of the answer).

Comment: a very good resource, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a full list, but these are the ones you were interested in:

```
BluetoothDeviceConnectFailedNotification
BluetoothDeviceConnectSuccessNotification
BluetoothDeviceDisconnectFailedNotification // haven't confirmed this one
BluetoothDeviceDisconnectSuccessNotification
```

Here are some others:

```
BluetoothConnectabilityChangedNotification // fires when bluetooth is turned on/off
BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification // seems to fire once at app start)
BluetoothPowerChangedNotification
BluetoothDeviceDiscoveredNotification
BluetoothDeviceRemovedNotification
BluetoothPairingUserNumericComparisionNotification
BluetoothPairingPINResultSuccessNotification
```

Answer (score 1):

Add before you call `[BluetoothManager sharedInstance]`:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter(),
                                    NULL,
                                    bluetoothCallback,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

and somewhere in this implementation the method void bluetoothCallback:

```
void bluetoothCallback (CFNotificationCenterRef center,
                 void *observer,
                 CFStringRef name,
                 const void *object,
                 CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    if (CFStringGetCharacterAtIndex(name, 0) == 'B') { // stupid way to filter for only 'B'luetooth notifications
        NSLog(@"%@", name);
    }
}
```

Your console log shows you all bluetooth notifications now.

Comment: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738387/1864294 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13150904/1864294