# Receive BluetoothManager notifications in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth, notifications, iphone-privateapi

I'm using the BluetoothManager private framework in my app and I want to know how can I receive BluetoothManager notifications when the application is in background (ex: Receive the connected/disconected bluetooth notification in background).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
// global notification explorer
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter(),
    NULL, MyCallBack, NULL, NULL, 
    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

and receive the notifications:

```
// global notification callback
void MyCallBack (CFNotificationCenterRef center,void *observer,CFStringRef name,const void object,CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    NSLog(@"CallBack:CFN Name:%@ Data:%@", name, userInfo);
}
```